# Determine the total number of hits on an Elastic Beanstalk application

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a flask app on AWS's Elastic Beanstalk. I'm wondering if there's any way for me to determine the **total number of hits** that my website has received. Does anyone know whether this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Google Analytics ([analytics.google.com](http://analytics.google.com)) to track my websites' traffic. It's pretty simple to use. You add your website to your Analytics account, and it gives you a javascript snippet that you can paste onto a web page.

The general practice is to paste the snippet into a base template so it appears everywhere on your website.